# How to find an accessible color by changing lightness only?

Tags: colors, accessibility, w3c, contrast, wcag2.0

Is the following hypothesis true?

For any given color:

```
{ Hue, Saturation, Lightness_1 }
```

there exists:

```
Lightness_2
```

such that the [contrast ratio](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#contrast-ratiodef) between:

```
{ Hue, Saturation, Lightness_1 }
```

and

```
{ Hue, Saturation, Lightness_2 }
```

is at least `4.5`.

**Bonus question:** How could I find such `Lightness_2`?

Comment: [Cross-post](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/82319/17023)

Answer (score 0):

If you install the Google Chrome accessibility developer tools extension, then you will see that the accessibility information for a node whose color contrast does not match 4.5:1 will also include information on what color combination is closest that will.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/accessibility-developer-t/fpkknkljclfencbdbgkenhalefipecmb?hl=en

The algorithm for doing this is included in the GitHub repository: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/accessibility-developer-tools/blob/master/src/js/Color.js#L267

Comment: So, is my hypothesis true or false?